# SQL Server : UNPIVOT query to achieve results as shown below?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, unpivot

I have a dataset with 50,000 records. The format is like shown below.

```
Handle | Category | A   | B   | C   | Misc Info
-------|----------|-----|-----|-----|-----------
H1     | X        | 100 | 120 | 150 | kk
H2     | Y        | 100 | 120 | 150 | mm
H3     | Z        | 100 | 120 | 150 | nn
```

I want the query result to look like the one shown below.

```
Handle | Category | Option | Value | Misc Info
-------|----------|--------|-------|-----------
H1     | X        | A      | 100   | kk
H1     |          | B      | 120   |
H1     |          | C      | 150   |
-------|----------|--------|-------|-----------
H2     | Y        | A      | 100   | mm
H2     |          | B      | 120   |
H2     |          | C      | 150   |
-------|----------|--------|-------|-----------
H3     | Z        | A      | 100   | nn
H3     |          | B      | 120   |
H3     |          | C      | 150   |
```

What will be the T-SQL query to achieve this?

Comment: This seems to be a presentation issue rather than a sql problem. Can't you handle this using code on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `cross apply`:

```
select v.handle, v.category, v.option, v.value, v.misc_info
from t cross apply
     (values (handle, category, 'A', a, misc_info, 1),
             (handle, NULL, 'B', b, NULL, 2),
             (handle, NULL, 'C', c, NULL, 3)
     ) v(handle, category, option, value, misc_info, priority)
order by handle, priority;
```

Usually, this sort of transformation is best handled at the presentation layer.  This is especially true when the ordering of the result set is important -- an `order by` is needed because results sets are *unordered* without an explicit `order by`.

(The ordering is important because `category` and `misc_info` sometimes depend on "previous" values.)

In this case, the work isn't actually very hard in SQL.  Just remember not to rely on the default ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that:

```
SELECT Handle, Category, "A" AS Option, A as Value, Misc, Info
UNION ALL
SELECT Handle, Category, "B" AS Option, B as Value, Misc, Info
UNION ALL
SELECT Handle, Category, "C" AS Option, C as Value, Misc, Info
ORDER BY Category
```

But you need to do [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) if you need this query type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNPIVOT for this as shown below.

```
SELECT [Handle],[Category],[Option],[Value],[Misc_Info]
FROM
@data  
UNPIVOT 
(
  [Value] FOR [Option] IN (A,B,C)
) AS unpivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... I came up with something. Looks like it worked for me. Not sure if it is the most efficient.

```
SELECT 
    [Handle], 
    CASE [Category] 
        WHEN 'A' THEN [Category]
        ELSE ''
    END AS [Category],
    [Option],
    [Value],
    CASE [Misc Info]
        WHEN 'A' THEN [Misc Info]
        ELSE ''
    END AS [Misc Info],
FROM (
    SELECT [Handle], [Category], [Option], [Value], [Misc Info]
    FROM Test_Table
    UNPIVOT
    (
    [Value] for [Option] in ([A], [B], [C])
    ) as P
) as X;
```